# Using JSON Patch on Kubernetes yaml file

Tags: json, kubernetes, patch

I'm trying to use JSON Patch on one of my Kubernetes yaml file.

```
apiVersion: accesscontextmanager.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: AccessContextManagerServicePerimeter
metadata:
  name: serviceperimetersample
spec:
  status:
    resources:
    - projectRef:
        external: "projects/12345"
    - projectRef:
        external: "projects/123456"
    restrictedServices:
    - "storage.googleapis.com"
    vpcAccessibleServices:
      allowedServices:
      - "storage.googleapis.com"
      - "pubsub.googleapis.com"
      enableRestriction: true
  title: Service Perimeter created by Config Connector
  accessPolicyRef:
    external: accessPolicies/0123
  description: A Service Perimeter Created by Config Connector
  perimeterType: PERIMETER_TYPE_REGULAR
```

I need to add another project to the perimeter (spec/status/resources).

I tried using following command:

```
kubectl patch AccessContextManagerServicePerimeter serviceperimetersample --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/status/resources/-/projectRef", "value": {"external": {"projects/01234567"}}}]'
```

But it resulted in error:

```
The request is invalid: the server rejected our request due to an error in our request
```

I'm pretty sure that my path is not correct because it's nested structure. I'd appreciate any help on this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the `CustomResource` you're using so I can't test this, but I think this should work:

```
kubectl patch AccessContextManagerServicePerimeter serviceperimetersample --type='json' -p='[{"op":"add","path":"/spec/status/resources/2","value":{"projectRef":{"external":"projects/12345"}}}]'
```